# How to manage Android MediaPlayer state, errors, and exceptions?

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, media

I am trying to play a short sound byte after processing a scanned bar code. My code currently works fine for as many as twenty scans. However, eventually the MediaPlayer throws the following error repeatedly even after the app has been killed:

```
MediaPlayer: Error (-38, 0)

MediaPlayer: Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0xXXXXXX, mCurrentState=0
```

--the X's representing a random 6 digit memory address--

I originally was playing the sound byte off of the UI thread. Since I've created a handler in an attempt to mitigate the issue. This is how I access the handler:

```
    try {
            mHandler.post(mScanFeedback);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println("Media player state error");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the code for the handler:

```
private Runnable mScanFeedback = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        if(getString(R.string.working).equals(mStatusHourly)) {
            final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.bleep_working);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    System.out.println("Media Player onError callback!");
                    return true;
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(150);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        } else if(getString(R.string.not_working).equals(mStatusHourly)) {
            final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.bleep_not_working);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    System.out.println("Media Player onError callback!");
                    return true;
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(275);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Audio feedback failed as status was indeterminate.");
        }

    }
};
```

In the beginning I didn't call release() and adding it hasn't seemed to make it work any better or worse. The onError callback is never called when the problem occurs. I've tried to reset() the media player after each time it is played but that throws an error. Right now I resort to restarting the phone to keep my Logcat from being unusable by the onslaught of the same two error lines repeated continually.

I'm using zxing's bar code scanner and there is a short beep played within that activity as confirmation that the bar code has been captured. A small part of me wonders if their isn't a conflict there.

I'm still new to programming and this is my first question on stack overflow. Let me know if I should have provided any additional information or if I should try to keep it a little more lean.

Update:

I was unable to resolve the issue with the MediaPlayer. However, I was able to work around the issue by switching to a SoundPool implementation. The class below provides the needed functionality.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;

public class SoundManager {

private  SoundPool mSoundPool;
private  HashMap mSoundPoolMap;
private  AudioManager  mAudioManager;
private  Context mContext;

public void initSounds(Context theContext) {
    mContext = theContext;
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap();
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
}

public void addSound(int index, int SoundID) {
    mSoundPoolMap.put(index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
}

public void playSound(int index) {
    float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mSoundPool.play(index, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);
}

public void playLoopedSound(int index) {
    float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    streamVolume = streamVolume / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mSoundPool.play(index, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, -1, 1f);
}
}
```

Which I then accessed from my Activity with:

```
mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.bleep_working);
mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.bleep_not_working);
mSoundManager.playSound(1);
mSoundManager.playSound(2);
```